# Reverse for 'editPost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editPost/(?P<postslug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am getting this error inside below template

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="date">{{ post.created_date }}</div>
                  <div class="title">
                    {{ post.text }}
                    {{ post.slug }}
                    <a href="{% url 'editPost' post.slug %}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                    <a onClick="delete_post('{{post.slug}}','{{post_id}}')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting the error in this line

```
<a href="{% url 'editPost' post.slug %}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

I displayed {{post.slug}} just before this line and commenting the link line just to make sure post.slug has some content. It looks post.slug has valid slug information.

I also tried passing just some string instead of post.slug like below then it was working

```
<a href="{% url 'editPost' 'some_string' %}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

my urls.py is like below

```
path('editPost/<postslug>/',views.editPost, name='editPost')
```

Can someone help me to find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error because out of all the posts one post has empty slug field which was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your url pattern as:

```
path('editPost/<slug:postslug>/',views.editPost, name='editPost')
```

Also change the link as :

```
<a href="{% url 'editPost' some_string %}" >
```

Comment: Its didn't work. Got this error. Reverse for 'editPost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editPost/(?P<postslug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: You should also remove the `'` in the `<a>` tag. Check the edit.

Comment: I am using this <a href="{% url 'editPost' post.slug %}" >.  I used this <a href="{% url 'editPost' 'some_string' %}" >  just to test if it working if I pass some string. It's working this way but not when I pass post.slug

Comment: The error is complaining about the `post.slug`; it seems like there is no value in it. Not sure why.

Comment: I found the error. Out of all the posts one post has empty slug field. That's why it was complaining. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, that the `arguments '('',)'` part of the error (argument is empty)